# Migrate from Open Source Cassandra to Datastax Enterprise

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

We have our current production cluster running on `Cassandra 2.2.4`

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.4 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]
```

We want to migrate this setup to a new cluster with `DSE 5.0` without disturbing our current production.

What are the steps to do this, with zero/minimal downtime?

1. We want to have this as a separate cluster.
2. Can we use sstableloader from source to destination cluster and do a sstableupgrade at destination?
3. Should we stop compaction on the existing cluster, when running sstabloader?
4. How to transfer newly created sstables because of the production traffic?
5. Should we make application to write to both clusters, but only read from the old cluster, until new cluster is in sync with old cluster?
6. Should we run sstableloader from old data directory or from snapshot directory. What is the difference between the 2 approaches?

Answer (score 0):

1. Setup your new cluster using DSE 5.0
2. Begin writing to both of your clusters
3. SCP your SSTables over from the old cluster to the new cluster
4. Use sstableloader, from your new cluster, on the SSTables you just copied to the new cluster.

**Should we run sstableloader from old data directory or from snapshot directory. What is the difference between the 2 approaches?**

Depends, the snapshots are exactly that, a snapshot of a specific state your cluster was in at some point in time. If you want the freshest data, use the SSTables currently in your data directory.

Comment: 1. The Cassandra version in the current cluster is 2.2.4, whereas with DSE 5.0, the new cluster will have Cassandra 3.0. Is upgradesstable not required?

Comment: 2. If the old and new cluster differ in no. of nodes/replication factor, how do I scp from old to new. Which nodes to choose to scp from and to?

Comment: 1. No, sstableloader streams in the data so the data gets "replayed"
2. The same as 1, the data gets re streamed and its token range gets determined by the new cluster.

Comment: If I scp the sstables to the new cluster and invoke sstableloader from there, it will create another set of sstables based on the new cluster's configuration. Should I then remove the sstables that I initially scpied?         From how many nodes in the old cluster should I scp, is it number_of_nodes/replication_factor of the old cluster?

Comment: Yes, essentially you are just streaming the data from your old SSTables back into Cassandra. You would want to SCP all of your SSTables as there isn't really a way to know which data is in which SSTables.

Comment: I guess we need to do some additional steps if we need to run sstableloader on the same node where we want to load data.  I am unable to follow this http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/bulk-loading.  Can you pl. give the steps for it.

Comment: There was a mistake in the datacenter name in the create keyspace amd that is why the streaming failed. It did not throw any error also and hence I was clueless. The problem is resolved now.